# Modify dataframe based on the unique levels of column and then combine values from 2 other columns inside them

Tags: r

I have the dataframe below and I want to modify it in a way that will have 3 columns `Election,Party_1 and Party_2` and inside Party columns a paste between `Candidate` and `Voteshare`

```
df<-structure(list(ELECtion = c("PC_2009", "AC_2011", "PC_2014", 
"AC_2016", "PC_2019", "AC_2021", "PC_2009", "AC_2011", "PC_2014", 
"AC_2016", "PC_2019", "AC_2021"), Party = c("Party_1", "Party_1", 
"Party_1", "Party_1", "Party_1", "Party_1", "Party_2", "Party_2", 
"Party_2", "Party_2", "Party_2", "Party_2"), Candidate = c("Mr.Sen", 
"Dr.Kar", "Mr. Sen", "Dr.Kar", "Dr.Reddy", "Dr.Kar", "Dr.Dutta", 
"Mrs.Dondopani", "Mr. Das", "Mrs.Dondopani", "Mr,Das", "Mrs.Dondopani"
), Voteshare = c(0.2, 0.32, 0.12, 0.36, 0.005, 0.26, 0.15, 0.23, 
0.45, 0.28, 0.54, 0.38)), row.names = c(NA, -12L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

like

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `paste` + `pivot_wider`:

```r
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  mutate(cand_vote = paste(Candidate, paste0(Voteshare * 100, "%")), .keep = "unused") %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = "Party", values_from = "cand_vote")

#   ELECtion Party_1       Party_2          
#   <chr>    <chr>         <chr>            
# 1 PC_2009  Mr.Sen 20%    Dr.Dutta 15%     
# 2 AC_2011  Dr.Kar 32%    Mrs.Dondopani 23%
# 3 PC_2014  Mr. Sen 12%   Mr. Das 45%      
# 4 AC_2016  Dr.Kar 36%    Mrs.Dondopani 28%
# 5 PC_2019  Dr.Reddy 0.5% Mr,Das 54%       
# 6 AC_2021  Dr.Kar 26%    Mrs.Dondopani 38%
```

Answer (score 1):

We can `unite` the candidate and voteshare columns into a single variable, then `pivot_wider` to spread the data.
`scales::percent` converts fractions to percentages easily.

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

df |> 
    mutate(Voteshare = scales::percent(Voteshare)) |> 
    unite(c("Candidate", "Voteshare"),
          sep = " ",
          col = "value") |> 
    pivot_wider(names_from = Party,
                values_from = value)

# A tibble: 6 × 3
  ELECtion Party_1       Party_2            
  <chr>    <chr>         <chr>              
1 PC_2009  Mr.Sen 20.0%  Dr.Dutta 15.0%     
2 AC_2011  Dr.Kar 32.0%  Mrs.Dondopani 23.0%
3 PC_2014  Mr. Sen 12.0% Mr. Das 45.0%      
4 AC_2016  Dr.Kar 36.0%  Mrs.Dondopani 28.0%
5 PC_2019  Dr.Reddy 0.5% Mr,Das 54.0%       
6 AC_2021  Dr.Kar 26.0%  Mrs.Dondopani 38.0%
```